# Show that if $g:[a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then there exists a point $\bar{x}\in(a,b)$ such that $g(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b g(t)dt$

Tags: calculus

I used the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to show that if $g\in C[a,b]$ then we can define $g(x)=\int_a^x g(x)dx$, $x\in[a,b]$ and thus $g$ is differentiable and $g'(x)=g(x)$. Then since we now know that the function is differentiable and continuous then I used the MVT to get that $g'(x)=\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}$.

But how do I translate what I know to show that if $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then there exists a point $\bar{x}\in(a,b)$ such that $g(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b g(t)dt$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the idea, but there are some notation mistakes in your reasoning and perhaps you're confusing yourself. Let's see:

You want to prove that there exists some $\bar x\in[a,b]$ such that
$$g(\bar x)=\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bg(t)dt$$
Here is your first mistake. You forgot the bar over $x$.

Now, let's apply the FToC. If we define
$$G(x)=\int_a^xg(t)dt$$
(note the capital $G$, we could have used any other letter, capital or not, but never $g$, because we can't use the same letter for two different objects in the same reasoning), we know that $G$ is differentiable and $G'=g$. Now we apply the MVT to $G$, not to $g$, to see that there exists some $\bar x\in[a,b]$ such that
$$g(\bar x)=G'(\bar x)=\frac{G(b)-G(a)}{b-a}\stackrel *=\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bg(t)dt$$

At $(*)$ we applied Barrow's rule.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use two symbols for two functions. One function is $g(x)$, which is the function you are given, then you have a function $G(x)=\int_a^x g(x)dx$ and for which you know that $G'=g$. Your original statement, that $g'(x)=g(x)$, is not true in general.

My advice is that you rewrite your proof making sure you don't confuse $g$ and $G$, and then when you use MVT, everything should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach:** By the Extreme Value Theorem there are points $x_0$ and $x_1$ in $[a,b]$ such that $g(x_0)\le g(t)\le g(x_1)$ for all $t\in[a,b]$. By elementary properties of the integral, $g(x_0)\le (b-a)^{-1}\int_a^b g(t)\,dt\le g(x_1)$ as well. The Intermediate Value Theorem now yields $\bar x$ between $x_0$ and $x_1$ such that $g(\bar x) = (b-a)^{-1}\int_a^b g(t)\,dt$.